Can't get Grand Average in place of Grand Total in Pivot Table
My question is exactly the same as this one, but, for some reason I don't get, the answer doesn't work (or I don't read it right). Maybe something changed since then.
Let's say I have this. I get a count for of eventid for each user by day:

Now, I want the grand total column to show the average for each row, so the average daily count by user. But for each day, I do want the count for the user.
So, I right-click anywhere in the Grand Total column, the Summarize Values By > Average. And this is what I get:

Instead of updating the calculation for the Grand Total column, it did for the entire set of values.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

I don't believe that the post you linked to is exactly the same situation as yours - I'd suggest that in the example you linked to, the underlying data was such that summarising all rows by "Average" meant that the individual values still displayed as the user expected, and then the Grant Total worked OK.  Your case is different - you want "Count" in the individual user/data intersecting cells, but you want "Average" in the Grand Total.  A standard pivot table doesn't allow that.  There are plenty of different workaround solutions that you can find online with some simple searching

Aaaaah OK! That makes more sense then! I will add a separate column with an AVERAGE formula then. Somehow, I was under the impression that it was possible to calculate grant total independently of the value aggregation function. Thanks for correcting me!
